# Floating bottom bar jerky when moved

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, css-position

I created a page with a floating bar. The problem is that when I move the scroll bar on the right, the floating bottom bar is moving jerkily although it eventually is at bottom.

I tried to fix the jerky movement by either removing the background body image or removing the `overflow:auto` for `container-msg`. It works but I need to have those on. What can I do to make this movement smooth?

The HTML is:

```
<body style="background:#cfe1ed url(bg.jpg) repeat-x fixed;margin: 0;padding: 0;text-align: center;color: #404040;font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;">
<div id="container-msg" style="width: 900px;min-height: 500px;border: 0;overflow:auto;text-align: left;margin: 0 auto 0 auto;background:#FFF;">
  <p>h</p>
  <p>dfh</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>fg</p>
  <p>hf</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>g</p>
  <p>dfg</p>
  <p>dfh</p>
  <p>fg</p>
  <p>hfg</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>fgh</p>
  <p>fgh</p>
  <p>gfh</p>
  <p>fh</p>
  <p>dg</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>dfh</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>fg</p>
  <p>hf</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>g</p>
  <p>dfg</p>
  <p>dfh</p>
  <p>fg</p>
  <p>hfg</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>fgh</p>
  <p>fgh</p>
  <p>gfh</p>
  <p>fh</p>
  <p>dg</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>dfh</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>fg</p>
  <p>hf</p>
  <p>h</p>
  <p>fghf</p>
  <p>h</p>
</div>
<div id="music" style=" background:#CCC;display:block;position:fixed;height:35px;width:500px;bottom:0px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: BTW, I tested with Firefox 3.x but IE8 works fine without jerky movement

Comment: ff 3.5.2 - jerky. Does you tried z-index ?

Comment: Some people don't see the jerky slow movement of the bottom bar too. This is strange. Could be due to graphic card?

Comment: I tried z-index: 100 too. So basically it is on top

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working perfectly fine. However, make sure you add a VALID doctype else position:fixed will NOT work in IE7. For IE6, you will have to write a small javascript code to move it down each and every time.

Comment: Have you tried it in Firefox 3.x? Move the scrollbar quickly and watch for where the "black characters" touching the bottom bar. Seem that the refresh/rendering was not smooth.